# aov formula error term: contradictory examples

Tags: r

I've seen two basic approaches to generic formulas for within-subjects designs in R/`aov()` (`R` = random, `X` = dependent, `W`? = within, `B`? = between):

```
# Pure within: 
    X ~ Error(R/W1*W2...)
# or  
    X ~ (W1*W2...) + Error(R/(W1*W2...))

# Mixed:
    X ~ B1*B2*... + Error(R/W1*W2...)
# or  
    X ~ (B1*B2*...W1*W2...) + Error(R/(W1*W2...)+(B1*B2...))
```

That is, some advise never putting `W` factors outside the error term or `B` factors inside, while others put all (`B`, `W`) factors outside and inside, indicating in the error term which are nested within R.

Are these simply notational variants? Is there any reason to prefer one to the other as a default for performing ANOVA using `aov()`?

Answer (score 2):

I would always recommend putting all within-subjects variables inside and outside of the error term.

For pure within-subject analysis this means using the following formula:

```
X ~ (W1*W2...) + Error(R/(W1*W2...))
```

Here, all wihin-subjects effects are tested with repect to their appropriate error term.

In contrast, the formula `X ~ Error(R/W1*W2...)` does not allow you to test the effects of your variables.

The same principle holds for mixed designs (including between- and withins-subject variables). The correct formula is:

```
X ~ (B1*B2*...W1*W2...) + Error(R/(W1*W2...))
```

There is no need to use the between-variables twice in the formula. The model above is actually identical to `X ~ (B1*B2*...W1*W2...) + Error(R/(W1*W2...)+(B1*B2...))`.

This formula allows you to test both between- and within-subject effects with the correct error terms.

For more information, read [this](http://personality-project.org/r/r.anova.html) ANOVA tutorial.