# How are residuals of aov() calculated?

Tags: r

I'm wondering how residuals in aov() are calculated. I looked already for hours but can't figure it out.

I use an ANOVA for repeated measurements.

```
Data <- data.frame(subject = factor(rep(1:10, 3)),
                age = factor(c(rep(4, 10),
                               rep(10, 10),
                               rep(35, 10))),
                weight = c(20, 9, 16, 14, 30, 26, 26, 27, 13, 15,
                           27, 18, 30, 26, 43, 48, 38, 38, 22, 47,
                           50, 44, 52, 46, 64, 70, 73, 57, 54, 63))

ANOVA_MW <- aov(weight ~ age + 
                Error(subject / age),
                data = Data)
summary(ANOVA_MW)
```

I know that the following command gives me something.
    `round(ANOVA_MW$subject:age$residuals, 2)`

However, I get only 20 rather than 30 values. It starts with 11. This has propably something to do with the residuals of subject. I don't know.

The result of `proj(ANOVA_MW)` gives me the residuals that I calculated manually (value - personal mean - group mean + overall mean).

My question is, what are the other residuals above and why is everybody (so it feels) using them for normality testing?

I would love some helpful input. I already dove into the function but could not find an explanation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`residual sum of square = total sum of square - Factor sum of squares`

In your case, factor is age.

The residuals should be normally distributed, it is one of the assumption of [ANOVA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_variance).

Answer (score 0):

It seems O.K.
I suggest you to check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37497948/aov-error-term-in-r-whats-the-difference-bw-errorid-and-errorid-timevar) out.

You have `Error(subject/age)` term in your codes. So, `your Error: subject`'s df is 9 (10-1). And your `age`'s df is 2 (3-1). Finally, your `Error: subject:age Residuals`' df is 18 ((30-1)-(9+2)). So, `ANOVA_MW$subject:age` indicates these 20 (2+18) residuals.